# Can I achieve an underlined button on hover with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm beginning to learn Tailwind CSS and am trying to implement the button below. It's a blank button that highlights its bottom border on hover.

[image]

However, scanning through the docs, I can't seem to be able to recreate the effects.

Comment: Set a bottom border, make it transparent, and switch to a given color on hover. Use a transition to smooth out the effect. Entirely possible in Tailwind.

Comment: Which *specific* bit of that is causing you problems? It would help if you provided a live demo of what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the following to your tailwind.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
    variants: {
        extend: {
            // ...
           borderStyle: ['hover'],
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the following utilities to create the button.

```
<button class="p-4 font-bold font-sans border-b-2 border-double 
    border-transparent hover:border-current cursor-pointer select-none">
    Button
</button>
```

Finally, run `npm run prod`.

Answer (score 7):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
  <button class="text-6xl font-bold transition duration-150 border-b-8 border-transparent hover:border-purple-500">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transition class.
and check the transition documents in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).